# How can I execute a javascript function using lotus formula?

Tags: javascript, web, lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I am on the web, not client.

I need the user to press a button to execute some formula code and then execute this javascript:

```
function submit(){    
var fein = document.getElementsByName("Payer_FederalEIN").item(0);
    var address = document.getElementsByName("InternetAddress").item(0);
    var pass1 = document.getElementsByName("Password1").item(0);

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","url,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

When I use @URLOpen("javascript:submit()"), nothing happens and none of the formula code under that line is executed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use formula language in this context? Change the button to Javascript and put submit() (or the entire function) in there.

Comment: I need to execute formula code as well. I need to alter a field that is hidden in notes and when i do it in javascript, it throws the field to the bottom left of the form for some reason.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to do everything I wanted in javascript. Thanks.